# More Basic Javascript Animation Problems

Tags: javascript, html, animation, margin

So now I've tried to implement sideways movement:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Animation Bullshit</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animation.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
div = document.getElementById("div")

div.onmouseover = move, left; 
div.onmouseout = up;

var cHeight = div.style.height | 150;
var cLeft = div.style.marginLeft | 0;

function move() {
    if (cHeight < 300) {
        cHeight += 10;
        div.style.height = cHeight + "px";
        setTimeout (move, 20);
    }
}

function slide() {
    if (cLeft < 400) {
        cLeft += 10;
        div.style.marginLeft = cLeft + "px";
        setTimeout (slide, 20);
    }
}

function up() {
    if (cHeight > 150) {
        cHeight -= 10;
        div.style.height = cHeight + "px";
        setTimeout (up, 20);
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything loads, but when I mouse over the div, nothing happens. It doesn't even expand down. Suggestions?

It's telling me to add more details... Uh... The div is black, with an initial margin-left of 0px.

Comment: Have you checked your console? You should be getting an invalid left side assignment. `div.style.margin-left` won't work. try `div.style["margin-left"]`

Comment: to elaborate on @brbcoding's point, `.margin-left` is incorrect, you need to use the DOM name `.marginLeft`, or the string in brackets as he mentioned. the DOM name is ever-so-slightly more efficient, but either will work. also, the way you call your functions `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` is ... interesting.

Comment: Alright, I changed that and updated the original post with the changes. Still not working. I'm still getting an Uncaught Reference Error: Left is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used your code.
Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/tz2vcote/
I think its because you have not declared variable div with `var`. you should have checked firebug console.

checkout the updated one
http://jsfiddle.net/tz2vcote/2/
click on the div for slide effect.

Comment: Updated one worked. What'd you change, exactly? I mean, obviously yours uses clicking instead of mouseover, but the basic process of moving the div looks identical... How would I use mouseover instead of clicking?

Comment: It's not the div variable needing to be declared with var. I tried that with my old code and it still didn't work.

Comment: actually the way you assigned event handler function is wrong.  div.onmouseover = move, left; Instead, you wrap both functionality into 1 single function and assign it. like div.onmouseover = doBoth; where doBoth is a function which performs both the function.